# Identificar elementos com xPath

Tags: xpath

Eu queria identificar o seguinte elemento em uma página:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtData" type="text" value="19/01/2015" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtData" style="font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;width:120px;" />
```

Estou utilizando a seguinte *query* para localizar o elemento:

```
$node = $xpath->query("//input[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtData']");
```

1. A *query* está correta?
2. Qual a melhor forma de conseguir o `value` desse *input*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pegar o `value` é necessário colocar `@value` no final da *query*, ficando assim:

```
$node = $xpath->query("//input[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtData']/@value");
```

Como o *xpath* não retorna *strings*, mas nós(*nodes*), para obter o valor do node pode-se fazer:

```
$node = $xpath->query("//input[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtData']/@value");
echo $node->item(0)->value;
```

<kbd>[**xPathTest Demo**](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/7f9143758d33e8ea96cab9bcf967245e)</kbd>

Comment: Obrigado,mas quando eu coloco o "->value" ele dá esse erro:"Notice: Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$value in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\teste.php on line 51" você sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Continua falando que não existe essa função.

Comment: Funcionou,valeu